# Warning: Division by zero in Wordpress

Tags: php

> Warning: Division by zero in /home/content/p3nexnas06_data03/99/2164799/html/wp-content/themes/morpheus/template-sectioned.php on line 102

I started getting this message after removing an image from my media library. Here is what line 102 and surrounding lines look like of `template-sectioned.php`:

```
if (!empty($bgParallax)) {
                    $bgtype = get_post_meta($bgParallax, 'coll_bg_type', true);
                    switch ($bgtype) {
                        case 'image':
                            $bgImg = get_post_meta($bgParallax, 'coll_bg_img', true);
                            $dim = wp_get_attachment_image_src(coll_get_attachment_id($bgImg), 'full');
                            $bg_output .= '<img class="coll-bg-image js-coll-lazy"
                                    src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCNdjYAAAAAIAAeIhvDMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
                                    width="' . $dim[1] . '"
                                    height="' . $dim[2] . '"
                                    data-coll-ar="' . $dim[1] / $dim[2] . '" //line 102
                                    data-coll-src="' . $bgImg . '"
                                    alt="bg image" />';
```

LINE 102:

```
data-coll-ar="' . $dim[1] / $dim[2] . '"
```

Comment: Use a ternary to check if `$dim[2] != 0`, and if it is set it as `0` -> `data-coll-ar="' . ($dim[2] != 0 ? $dim[1] / $dim[2] : 0). '"`

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Do you not understand what is happening or just do not know how to fix it?

Comment: I think it's more embarrassing to bribe developers on stackoverflow, personally.

Comment: This is not a programmer for hire web site. There are plenty of them out there. We do what we do to help the community. Offering to pay insults the core beliefs of StackOverflow.

Comment: *"(Will Pay For Fastest Solution!)"* - Just a lot of bullsh*t if you ask me. This, as per your [original title](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27735253/1). Don't do this type of thing here. Hire a developer next time, go on Freelancer.com or http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can check if it is not 0 with a ternary operator:

```
//This line is extracted from the full assignment! (See the full assignment in OP's code)
data-coll-ar="' . ( ($dim[2] !== 0) ? $dim[1] / $dim[2] : 0 ) . '"
```

Comment: I'd of asked to get paid "first" ;-)

Comment: Btw it wasn't me that down voted but i think I see why it was. Unless you look closely at the context it looks like the expression is a string

Comment: @andrew Nobody down Vote, but it's a good call! I'll updated my answer so it's obvious, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This answer isn't meant as a quick solution, which is what the OP wants. **Vote for Rizier123's answer for that**. It's a piggy-back so please keep the vote rep on Rizier123.

According to [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` function returns this :

```
[0] => url
[1] => width
[2] => height
[3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original.
```

So as Rizier123 suggested, you could simply add a fail-save to see if the height is 0, and if so, avoid dividing by it and just set the `data-coll-ar` value to 0 instead. But that is simply masking the problem. You'll still have an image with 0 height and it won't appear on your web page; and, you don't know if the width has a value or if it is also 0 or if anything else is wrong with the data.

I would, in addition to Rizier123's patch, add error checking up the context hierarchy to either the switch or to the upload handler even. Replace bad images with a placeholder image, or ensure people are attaching valid images before they even get in your system. Put some intuitive error messaging on the screen to guide the user to enforce quality data as early as possible.

Comment: That is some good research! Very nice